# Is it possible to fine-tune BERT to do retweet prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, bert-language-model

I want to build a classifier that predicts if user `i` will retweet tweet `j`.

The dataset is huge, it contains 160 million tweets. Each tweet comes along with some metadata(e.g. does the retweeter follow the user of the tweet).

the text tokens for a single tweet is an ordered list of BERT ids. To get the embedding of the tweet, you just use the ids (So it is not text)

Is it possible to fine-tune BERT to do the prediction? if yes, what do courses/sources do you recommend to learn how to fine-tune? (I'm a beginner)

I should add that the prediction should be a probability.

If it's not possible, I'm thinking of converting the embeddings back to text then using some arbitrary classifier that I'm going to train.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want to make a binary classification based on two features, user `i` and tweet `j`, to determine if `i` will retweet `j`? Or are you making a binary classification that a tweet `j` will get retweeted (by any user)?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 No not only based on two features, I haven't really figured out what features to use yet... The prediction should be personalized though, so for each user, I'd have to create a user and tweet profile that describes the interests induced by doing NLP, then from that extract feature values. Is it clear or did I make it worse haha?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question without using the term "feature". What is the input to your classification algorithm? For specifically, I know that you want to create a model that determines `y=f(x)`. I understand that `y` will be binary decision `retweet / not retweet`. What is the input `x` here? Is it just the body of the tweet `j`?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, To be honest, I'm not quite sure yet, but from a high-level perspective, it should be features describing the particular tweet and user I'm trying to predict for. An example of a feature would be the similarity degree between the user profile and the content of the tweet. The user profile could contain the topics of interests (e.g., football etc.) of the user. I appreciate you taking the time to help me!

Comment: @Calvin from my understanding, you want to distinguish topics of interest then the features of the model in your case would be the content of the tweet. Then you could classify it with a "classifier model" such as BERT and determine it's topic. Now could you please tell us what you want to do next? Maybe you want to sort those tweets for your own interest and read them at your leisure time? what do you have in mind with this classification?

Comment: @Calvin what happened to the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fine-tune BERT, and you can use BERT to do retweet prediction, but you need more architecture in order to predict if user *i* will retweet tweet *j*.

Here is an architecture off the top of my head.

[image]

At a high level:

1. Create a dense vector representation (embedding) of user *i* (perhaps containing something about the user's interests, such as sports).
2. Create an embedding of tweet *j*.
3. Create an embedding of the combination of the first two embeddings together, such as with concatenation or hadamard product.
4. Feed this embedding through a NN that performs binary classification to predict retweet or non-retweet.

Let's break this architecture down by item.

To create an embedding of user *i*, you will need to create some kind of neural network that accepts whatever features you have about the user and produces a dense vector. This part is the most difficult component of the architecture. This area is not in my wheelhouse, but a quick google search for "user interest embedding" brings up this research paper on an algorithm called [StarSpace](https://medium.com/deep-learning-hk/starspace-mining-and-embedding-user-interests-28081937f95). It suggests that it can "obtain highly informative user embeddings according to user behaviors", which is what you want.

To create an embedding of tweet *j*, you can use any type of neural network that takes tokens and produces a vector. Research prior to 2018 would have suggested using an LSTM or a CNN to produce the vector. However, BERT (as you mentioned in your post) is the current state-of-the-art. It takes in text (or text indices) and produces a vector for each token; one of those tokens should have been the prepended `[CLS]` token, which commonly is taken to be the representation of the whole sentence. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-to-the-rescue-17671379687f) provides a conceptual overview of the process. It is in this part of the architecture that you can fine-tune BERT. [This webpage](https://mccormickml.com/2019/07/22/BERT-fine-tuning/) provides concrete code using PyTorch and the Huggingface implementation of BERT to do this step (I've gone through the steps and can vouch for it). In the future, you'll want to google for "BERT single sentence classification".

To create an embedding representing the combination of user *i* and tweet *j*, you can do one of many things. You can simply concatenate them together into one vector; so if user *i* is an M-dimensional vector and tweet *j* is an N-dimensional vector, then the concatenation produces an (M+N)-dimensional vector. An alternative approach is to compute the hadamard product (element-wise multiplication); in this case, both vectors must have the same dimension.

To make the final classification of retweet or not-retweet, build a simple NN that takes the combination vector and produces a single value. Here, since you are doing binary classification, a NN with a logistic (sigmoid) function would be appropriate. You can interpret the output as the probability of retweeting, so a value above 0.5 would be to retweet. See [this webpage](https://chrisalbon.com/deep_learning/keras/feedforward_neural_network_for_binary_classification/) for basic details on building a NN for binary classification.

In order to get this whole system to work, you need to train it all together [end-to-end](https://www.quora.com/What-does-it-mean-for-a-neural-network-to-be-trained-end-to-end). That is, you have to get all the pieces hooked up first and train it rather than training the components separately.

Your input dataset would look something like this:

```
user                          tweet                  retweet?
----                          -----                  --------
20 years old, likes sports    Great game             Y
30 years old, photographer    Teen movie was good    N
```

If you want an easier route where there is no user personalization, then just leave out the components that create an embedding of user *i*. You can use BERT to build a model to determine if the tweet is retweeted without regard to user. You can again follow the links I mentioned above.

Comment: To be clear, you are using BERT only for creating embeddings and are trying to use `some NN` to be the real model to make those decisions. Why can't OP simply use an `Embedding` layer to do it instead of a heavy and large model??

Comment: As you yourself said `BERT is indeed a classification model` so why not use it instead? OP is a beginner so he would like simple architecture....

Comment: @neelg: You can find the answer to your questions in the very first sentence of my post.

Comment: I don't see the diagram showing that BERT makes the prediction. It may not be clear to all of us but seeing the label on it seems that it is used as an `Embedding` layer rather than a classification model...

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in the last sentence of my post.

Answer (score -2):

There is already an answer on this in [Data Science SE](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/46377/can-bert-do-the-next-word-predict-task), which explains why BERT **cannot** be used for prediction. Here is the gist:

> BERT can't be used for next word prediction, at least not with the current state of the research on masked language modeling.
>
> BERT is trained on a **masked** language modeling task and therefore you cannot "predict the next word". You can only mask a word and ask BERT to predict it given the rest of the sentence (both to the left and to the right of the masked word).

But as I understand from your case that you want to do 'classification' then BERT is fully equipped to do that. Please refer to the [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-for-dummies-step-by-step-tutorial-fb90890ffe03) I have posted below. This will help you to classify the tweets according to its topic so you may then view them in your Leisure time.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! But I don't understand how retweet prediciton is the same as next word production. I'm aware that BERT is not a language model so it cannot be used to predict the next word. But I feel like this is totally different two things

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by that but if you want to train a classifier why are you trying to use BERT? Instead, you can use some other custom made model that acts as a classifier for your data. Which part is confusing you?

Comment: I want to use BERT because I need to do some NLP tasks to extract features from the tweets. The problem is as follows: given a user i and tweet j, predict the probability that i will retweet j. I have never fine-tuned a model, that's why I'm asking if it's even possible

Comment: Yes. It is possible. A simple Google lookup gets me this link which I think is apt for your experience level ==> {https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-for-dummies-step-by-step-tutorial-fb90890ffe03}

Comment: @neelg: What does next word prediction have to do with classifying if a retweet occurred? Also, I don't understand your statement `if you want to train a classifier why are you trying to use BERT`. BERT is indeed a classification model.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I think he misunderstood my question, that's all.